# Mule (Dataweave) transform Json data to List<Map>

Tags: mule

I have this Json Data I want to

```
{"universes":[{"path":"Universes/demo","name":"eFashion"},{"path":"Universes","name":"Cool"}]}
```

From this I want to Map path and name to `List<Map>` 
 application/java

```
{
 name :
 path :
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow take a tour [Go through How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps you for more view s and some Answers .

Comment: You need to update the code that you tried & where you stuck up these things helps folks to help you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the map operator for mapping all the elements

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.universes map {
    path: $.path,
    name: $.name
}
```

Notice that you access the value for each element using $, also the map operator receive the list of elements "payload.universes"